Problem with share folder on Remmina 1.4.35
I updated to Ubuntu 24.04 and the Remmina versión 1.4.35. I cant shared folder anymore.
When i want to configure the shared folder it dos not appear the link to select the folder and when i try writing the path ot does not work. Any solution to suggest?

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
